# Trigger node.js when changes made in apache mysql

Tags: mysql, apache, node.js

I'm building a simple commenting system using node and i need to configure this in a PHP project running in Apache server. So, i need to trigger node.js when some changes made in MySQL database table present in the Apache server. So, i need to know whether it is possible to do this in a Apache server? If so, then how to do that? Any idea or suggestions on this are greatly welcome. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are few options you could take, but I don't think you can get some sort of triggered action from within MySQL or Apache. IMHO, you these are the approaches you can take:

- you can expose a HTTP API from node and every time you need to notify the node app, you could simply insert the data into MySQL using PHP and then issue a simple GET request to trigger node.
- You could use some sort of queuing system (rabbitmq, redis, etc.) to manage the messages to and from the two application, hence orchestrating the flow of the data between the two apps (and later the db).
- you could poll the database from node and check for new rows to be available. This is fairly inefficient and quite tricky, but it sounds more close to what you want.